# Find widest subset on which Fourier series can be integrated and derived term by term

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

As part of one problem **I need to find the widest subset of $\mathbb{R}$** on which the obtained Fourier series can be integrated and derived term by term.

I found that it has something to do with uniform convergence, but I can't really apply anything I've read about it so far.

The Fourier series is: $$f(t)=\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left ( \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{4n^2-1} \right )\cos(2nt)$$

Note: I can prove absolute convergence (from which uniform convergence follows) but I don't see how I can apply it to certain interval $[a,b]$ where I can discuss the bounds $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The series converges absolutely and uniformly on all of $\mathbb R$, by the Weierstrass M test, because the series $\sum \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{4n^2-1}\right)$ converges absolutely.

Comment: A series of functions that converges may be differentiated term by term if the derived series converges uniformly and is of continuous functions. That is, if $f_n$ is continuously differentiable and $\sum f_n$ converges and $\sum f_n'$ converges uniformly then if $f$ is the sum of the former series we have $f'=\sum f_n'$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29: Yes, and have you tested whether in this case $\sum f_n '$ converges uniformly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for all $t \in \Bbb R$,

$$\left| \left ( \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{4n^2-1} \right )\cos(2nt) \right| \le \left| \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{4n^2-1} \right| \underbrace {|\cos (2nt)|} _{\le 1} \le \left| \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{4n^2-1} \right| = \frac 1 {4n^2-1}$$

and $\sum \frac 1 {4n^2-1}$ is convergent (use the limit comparison test and compare it with $\sum \frac 1 {n^2}$, which is known to be convergent), so by [Weierstrass's M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) the series $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \left ( \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{4n^2-1} \right )\cos(2nt)$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $\Bbb R$, therefore it may be integrated term by term on any interval $[a,b] \subset \Bbb R$.

Comment: Is uniform convergence sufficient to conclude term by term differentiability? I'm not so sure. The Fourier series of a periodic "triangle" function converges uniformly, but the function is not differentiable everywhere. I think the function in the OP will also have "corners" where it is not differentiable.

Comment: I think it needs to be continuous

Comment: @Bungo: Uniform convergence is enough if each function in the series (in our case $\cos (2nt)$) is integrable / differentiable.

Comment: @tyr Continuity is not sufficient, as the example of the triangle function shows. A sufficient condition for termwise differentiability is: (1) the series converges uniformly, (2) the derivative of each term is continuous, and (3) the series of termwise derivatives converges uniformly. However, I don't believe this is a necessary condition.

Comment: @AlexM. But there are Fourier series which converge uniformly to functions which are not everywhere differentiable (as I believe is the case here), so  termwise differentiation may not work at every point in the domain.

Comment: @Bungo: Give me a bit of time, I'm thinking about it.

Comment: @Bungo: What bothers me is the square in $4n^2-1$; had there been any other power $>2$, the result would have been easy to obtain. As a side-note, $f$ is derivable on $\Bbb R$, I've computed the sum with Mathematica and it's a finite sum of terms involving $\arctan$ of some imaginary exponentials.

Comment: @AlexM. Interesting, I don't have Mathematica on this PC so I just plotted the sum of the first 50 terms, and it looked like there were going to be corners at $t=\pm \pi/2$. (Partial sums can be misleading!) This seemed plausible given the similarity of these coefficients to those of the triangle function.

Comment: @Bungo: $f= \frac 2 \pi + \frac 1 \pi \textrm e ^{- \textrm i t} (-2 \textrm e ^{- \textrm i t} + \arctan \textrm e ^{- \textrm i t} + \textrm e ^{2 \textrm i t} \arctan \textrm e ^{- \textrm i t} + \arctan \textrm e ^{\textrm i t} + \textrm e ^{2 \textrm i t} \arctan \textrm e ^{\textrm i t})$. If Mathematica is right, then $f$ is even analytic.

Comment: It turns out that $f(x) = |\cos(x)|$. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/699257/169852) for a derivation. Consequently, $f$ is not differentiable at $x = \pm \pi/2$.

Comment: @Bungo: Nice find! This shows that Mathematica was wrong - it wouldn't be the first time. On the other hand, knowing what function that series sums up to is not a nice proof. I was thinking about using Sobolev's embedding theorem, but that approach fails too - again, because of the square in $4n^2 - 1$ (any power $>2$ would have done the job). I ask the OP to unaccept my answer, since it is obviously incomplete (and missing the more difficult half).

Comment: Some context from the OP would be good. In the first sentence, he mentions that this is "part of one problem" and that this is "the **obtained** Fourier series" (emphasis mine). Perhaps the problem started by defining $f(x) = |\cos(x)|$ and calculating the Fourier series was an earlier step. If not, I agree that this is not a nice proof. Unfortunately I can't see how to prove it directly from the series.

Comment: @Bungo: Exactly. You see, there are several results that give sufficient conditions for derivability, but I know of no result giving points where a function is *not* derivable. The problem seems thus so intractable, that I suspect its statement to be incomplete. On the other hand, if it is given that $f = |\cos|$, then the issue of its integrability / derivability is trivial and does not require its Fourier series.